# Filtering fusion tables

Tags: select, filter, where-clause, google-fusion-tables

I´m using app inventor 2 with fusion tables, and I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM  1nI-17Wnvd8Jvr2ALmd8zCh7RtM1DzpgNK3cRDN8y WHERE "Car='var1'"
```

var1 is a variable but it doesn't work. How can I use a variable in the filter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
"SELECT * FROM 1nI-17Wnvd8Jvr2ALmd8zCh7RtM1DzpgNK3cRDN8y WHERE Car="+var1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t work , do you have another idea??

Comment: Please click `edit` and add the 4-5 lines before your SELECT statement to your question.